# How to speed up cumulative concatenation with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string, group-by

I have this function which is very slow, essentially I need to create cumulative sequence of string.

I tried with NumPy but there was no time improvement.

```
def create_sequence_shifted(df) -> list:
    articles = []
    customers = df["CUSTOMER"].drop_duplicates()
    for customer in customers:
        tmp = df[df["CUSTOMER"]==customer].sort_values(by="DATE").reset_index(drop=True)
        i=0
        for x in tmp["DOCUMENT_CODE"].drop_duplicates():
            if i==0: 
                articles += [0]
                sequence = tmp[tmp["DOCUMENT_CODE"]==x]["PRODUCT_ID"].str.cat(sep =", ")
                i = 1
            else:
                articles += [sequence]
                sequence = articles[-1] +", " + tmp[tmp["DOCUMENT_CODE"]==x]["PRODUCT_ID"].str.cat(sep =", ")

    return articles
```

Starting data:

| CUSTOMER | DATE | DOCUMENT_CODE | ARTICLE_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/22 | a | x |
| 1 | 01/01/22 | a | y |
| 1 | 02/01/22 | b | z |
| 1 | 03/01/22 | d | w |
| 2 | 01/01/22 | c | x |

To:

| CUSTOMER | DATE | DOCUMENT_CODE | ARTICLE_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/22 | a | 0 |
| 1 | 02/01/22 | b | x,y |
| 1 | 03/01/22 | d | x,y,z |
| 2 | 01/01/22 | c | 0 |

Comment: You do not need loops to accomplish this, but can we see some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: can you provide an example of input/output?

Comment: @Enrico thanks, wan you also explain the logic? Your function doesn't run on the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you need a double `groupby`:

```
out = (
 df.groupby(['CUSTOMER', 'DATE', 'DOCUMENT_CODE'])
   ['ARTICLE_CODE'].agg(','.join)
   .groupby('CUSTOMER').shift(fill_value=0)
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
   CUSTOMER      DATE DOCUMENT_CODE ARTICLE_CODE
0         1  01/01/22             a            0
1         1  02/01/22             b          x,y
2         2  01/01/22             c            0
```

###### cumulated aggregation

```
sep = ','

out = (
 df.groupby(['CUSTOMER', 'DATE', 'DOCUMENT_CODE'])
   ['ARTICLE_CODE'].agg(sep.join)
   .groupby('CUSTOMER')
   .apply(lambda s: s.add(sep).cumsum().str[:-len(sep)].shift(fill_value=0))
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
   CUSTOMER      DATE DOCUMENT_CODE ARTICLE_CODE
0         1  01/01/22             a            0
1         1  02/01/22             b          x,y
2         1  03/01/22             d        x,y,z
3         2  01/01/22             c            0
```

Comment: Sorry, i miss one part. The logic is that the documents are shifted but the concatenation is cumulative. Check the data, i fix it

Comment: Can you check the update?

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 = df.groupby(['CUSTOMER', 'DATE', 'DOCUMENT_CODE']]).apply(lambda row: ','.join(row['ARTICLE_CODE'])).reset_index()
df2.columns = df.columns
df2['ARTICLE_CODE'] = df2['ARTICLE_CODE'].apply(lambda x: x if len(x) > 1 else 0)
```

So you're essentially grouping by CUSTOMER, DATE and DOCUMENT_CODE, and then concatenating the article codes by a comma. The group by does that. After there is there is a filter that says if there is only a single code, return 0.

(If you want to keep your code and you've already gone with numpy arrays, you can also try the numba and jit compiling to see if it gets sped up)

Comment: Thanks, that's good but not complete. The logic is to concatenate the articles,  document over document, but considering also the past documents. So with a cumulative logic

Comment: Check the data, i fix it